# wpf bring up a context menu dynamically on an editable cell in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

The scenario is:

I have a datagrid that uses a DataTable as an ItemsSource.

```
dataGrid.ItemsSource = LogFileItemDataTable.DefaultView;
```

I can inline edit fields in there, and one is a textbox.

If it is a text box, I'd like to be able to select some text and dynamically bring up a context menu with item "Contains..." and "Does not contain..." and then do some stuff.

But I was having trouble trying to get an event and setting a context menu to the textbox that is currently being edited.

My datagrid does not explicitly setup columns, it just uses ItemsSource with a datatable.

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10,35,10,40">
  </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on a datagrid template column, in the template add the following:

```
<TextBox
  Name="cxmTextBox" 
  Grid.Row="1"
  AcceptsReturn="True"
  AcceptsTab="True"
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
  TextWrapping="Wrap"
>
  <TextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu 
      Name="cxm"
      Opened="CxmOpened"
    >
      <MenuItem 
        Header="Contains"
        Name="cxmItemContains" 
        Click="ClickContains" 
      />
      <MenuItem 
        Header="Does not contain" 
        Name="cxmItemNotContain"
        Click="ClickNotContain" 
      />
    </ContextMenu>
  </TextBox.ContextMenu>
</TextBox>
```

and add the code behind:

```
public void CxmOpened(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    // Only allow menu item if something is selected
    if (cxmTextBox.SelectedText == "")
        cxmItemContains.IsEnabled = cxmItemNotContains.IsEnabled = false;
    else
        cxmItemContains.IsEnabled = cxmItemNotContains.IsEnabled = true;

    // Only allow paste if there is text on the clipboard to paste.
    if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
        cxmItemPaste.IsEnabled = true;
    else
        cxmItemPaste.IsEnabled = false;
}

public void cxmItemContains(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { //do your stuff}

public void cxmItemNotContains(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { //do your stuff}
```

Comment: I do not use a template column. Sorry if my question was unclear, I've added some details to it.

Comment: if you want to have a custom column with a textbox with the context menu i'm afraid you need to work with the generate column event

Answer (score 0):

Use a `RichTextBox` for your `DataGrid` `Cell`s and then bring up `ContextMenu` from code by using `SelectionChanged` `Event`. Something like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First" IsReadOnly="False" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <RichTextBox x:Name="rtbFirst" SelectionChanged="rtbFirst_SelectionChanged">
                                <FlowDocument IsOptimalParagraphEnabled="True" IsHyphenationEnabled="True">
                                    <Paragraph>
                                       Some Text
                                    </Paragraph>
                                </FlowDocument>
                            </RichTextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Then

```
private void rtbFirst_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //do your context menu stuff here
        }
```